# OdbcCommand execution (ExecuteScalar/ ExecuteReader/ ExecuteNonQuery) all run slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc, azure-sql-database, query-performance

In my code I execute 2 kinds of queries which I execute on Azure SQL Server via the ODBC driver. They seem to execute very slow no matter what I do:

> DELETE FROM [tableName] WHERE ID = id
>
> INSERT INTO [tableName] (?, ..., ?) OUTPUT Inserted.PK VALUES (val_0, ..., val_N)

Both queries take 0.22-0.24 seconds to execute, leading to very low throughput of my program.

The queries are all inside the same using statement to reuse the connection:

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    ... //commands here
}
```

I have tried executing them the following ways, they all took a about the same time (0.22-0.24 sec) regardless of query or method:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand([SqlCommand], conn))
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

.

```
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand([SqlCommand], conn))
using (OdbcDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        primaryKey = reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

.

```
using (OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand([SqlCommand], conn))
    primaryKey = (long) com.ExecuteScalar();
```

**QUESTION** How may I write the queries so they run as fast as I expect them to?**

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use ODBC? I don't know if that is slower but it is certainly unusual when hitting azure sql. And there are many factors involved, how do you know the queries themselves are slow and it is not your VPN, network, etc?

Comment: It's best to use SqlClient in .NET unless you have specific reason to use ODBC instead. That said, how fast do you expect the queries to run? Where is the app code running? Is it the initial connection that takes time or the query itself? Connection pooling ought to improve performance in subsequent opens.

Comment: @Crowcoder the code will eventually be extended to use any database, so ODBC seems a reasonable design choice to keep the code changes to a minimum.

Comment: @Dan Guzman I expect an at least 2 orders of magniture less.

Comment: @Jeppe not all databases support odbc and even if they do  you may find issues with data type support.. I might suggest you code to an abstraction repository layer where you can change your data access without changing higher layers.